# undefined values while loading csv file for a d3 project

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, undefined

I'm trying to load a .csv file into an array with objects, but for some reason my values are undefined.

My code:

```
file = ("data/" + country + ".csv")
console.log(file)
d3.csv(file, function(error, dataset) {                     
    var data = [];
    console.log(dataset)
    for (i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
        var Period = {
                Year : dataset[i].Periods,
                numbers : dataset[i].numbers,
        }
        data.push(Period); 
    }
    console.log(data)               
    InitChart(data);                        
})
```

My csv looks like this:

```
Periods;numbers

"1998";"107"

"1999";"73"

"2000";"95"

"2001";"114"

"2002";"98"

"2003";"78"

"2004";"72"

"2005";"48"

"2006";"61"

"2007";"61"

"2008";"110"
```

Answer (score 3):

What you have is not a comma separated values but a semicolon separated one. So you should use `d3.dsv(';', file)`.